# How do I write this HTML code into Codeigniter form controller?

Tags: html, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I've some piece of code in HTML code,

```
<label class="color">
<input  type="checkbox" checked>
<span class="slider round"></span>
</label>
```

How do I convert this html code into codeigniter with form helper [Form Control](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/helpers/form_helper.html)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try with this code :**

**Note** : *First load `form_helper` either in `autoload.php` or in controller*

*Assuming that checkbox name is username*

```
<?=form_label(form_checkbox('username','',['checked' => TRUE]).'<span class="slider round"></span>','username',['class' => 'color']);?>
```

Output :

```
<label for="username" class="color">
  <input type="checkbox" name="username" value="" checked="checked"  />
  <span class="slider round"></span>
</label>
```

For more : https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/helpers/form_helper.html